# Eliminar filas con id duplicado en R

Tags: r

Tengo  datos como los siguientes:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,3,4),n=c("x","y","e","w"))
data
  id n
1  1 x
2  1 y
3  3 e
4  4 w
```

quiero obtener una salida como la siguiente:

```
data
  id n
1  1 x
3  3 e
4  4 w
```

es decir tener ids únicos discriminado el contendió de las otras columnas. Hasta ahora lo he logrado con:

```
library(dplyr)
data<-group_by(data,id)%>%summarise(n=n[1])
data
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id      n
  <dbl> <fctr>
1     1      x
2     3      e
3     4      w
```

sin embargo cuando hay más columnas como "n" esto resulta poco practico. Mi pregunta es si existe alguna manera de hacer esto dependiendo únicamente de la columna "id".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Usando DPLYR

Por lo que entiendo que buscas: **Obtener el primer registro de cada `id`** podrías simplemente usar [`slice()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html):

```
# Agrandamos un poco tu ejemplo con una columna más
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,3,4),n=c("x","y","e","w"), o=c(4,3,2,1))
data

  id n o
1  1 x 4
2  1 y 3
3  3 e 2
4  4 w 1

data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    slice(1)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
     id n         o
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl>
1    1. x        4.
2    3. e        2.
3    4. w        1.
```

El tema es cual de los registros de cada grupo quieres dejar y cuales ignorar, `slice()` en una alternativa simple y clara, pero si necesitas controlar el orden por el cual te vas a quedar con el primero [`top_n()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/top_n) sin duda puede ser mucho mejor ya que puedes controlar por el parámetro opcional `wt` la o las columnas por la cual ordenarás los grupos.

```
data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    top_n(n = 1, wt=-o) # Ordenamos por la columna 'o' ascendente
```

Asimismo, puedes consultar el sitio en inglés, [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766054/getting-the-top-values-by-group) tiene muchas otras opciones interesante para resolver este tema.

#### Usando R base

No puedo evitar ver como hacerlo en R base. Tampoco es demasiado complicado:

```
aggregate(. ~id, data, function(x){head(x, 1)})

  id n o
1  1 3 4
2  3 1 2
3  4 2 1
```

Obviamente, en este ejemplo, una de las columnas es un factor, por lo que deberemos convertirlo antes:

```
aggregate(.~id, data.frame(lapply(data, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE), function(x){head(x, 1)})

  id n o
1  1 x 4
2  3 e 2
3  4 w 1
```

Esto funcionaría como el `slice()`, el `head(x, 1)` simplemente se queda con el primer registro según el orden natural del objeto, si necesitamos establecer otro orden para determinar con cual registro quedarnos, deberemos ordenar antes el `data.frame` de acuerdo a ese criterio.

Y por último me estaba olvidando de [`duplicated()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html), todavía más sencillo:

```
data[!duplicated(data$id),]
```

Y más me olvidaba aún de de [`unique()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/unique.html), gracias @mpaladino

```
data[unique(data$id),]
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias! En este caso me quedo con la última solución, ya que no importa el orden. Creo que me hace falta un mejor conocimiento de R base :P

Comment: `data[unique(data$id), ]` hace lo mismo que la última opción que te da Patricio, sólo que no es necesario usar `!` para negar. También es función base.

Comment: muchas gracias mpaladino

Comment: Hola, acabo de utilizar la última solución ´data[unique(data$id),]´ y me devuelve un data frame lleno de NA. Alguien sabe que paso?

Comment: @RolandoTamayo, Lo único que se me ocurre es que `data` tenga solo `NA´s`, no veo forma en que se pueda dar lo que dices de otra manera, `unique(data$id)` solo retorna números de fila, es como si hicieras `data[c(1,2,3), ]`. `unique`podría eventualmente retornar un `NULL` si defines una variable inexistente, en cuyo caso no deberías obtener ninguna fila de `data`.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho volvi a obtener el mismo resultado un data.frame con solo NA´S. Esta vez con otro df y usando `df<-df[!duplicated(df$Localización),]` en el siguiente link un RData con el df que use https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-waAhYB4AE_8SF-yQ23OFy0uvkBiVj5l

Comment: Hola @RolandoTamayo, lamento decirte que lo he descargado y funciona perfectamente, hay 31 localizaciones duplicadas. Lo único que me hace un poco de ruido pero no debería tener nada que ver, es que la columna está acentuada, `Localización`. Prueba renombrarla, simplemente para quitarnos la duda.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho se que sonara raro pero sin modificar nada en el código comenzó a funcionar. Lo único que hice fue cargar ´dplyr´, para usar el ´slice()´, pero eso no debería afectar. Tratare de poner más atención la próxima vez que me vuelva a suceder.

Comment: @RolandoTamayo, he visto comportamientos parecidos con algunos objectos que se cargan de forma "Lazy", no sé si tendrá que ver, de todas formas no hay problema. saludos.